# How to correctly call method from jsf to ManagedBean

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

well I'm learning `jsf/hibernate` and I'm  having  trouble  understanding how to  correctly  call methods  to my `ManagedBean`
its  a simple CRUD   so  I need to pass vía the jsf form a `Ciclista` object, but since  the inputs  are `Ciclista` attributes  how do I pass the Object ? (how to create instance of it)   here's the code:

```
@Override
public String create(Ciclista c) {
    Session s = sFac.openSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
    s.save(c);
    s.getTransaction().commit();
    s.close();
    return "Administrador?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

and  jsf  form:

```
   <h:form class="form">
        <div id="input-wrapper">
            <h:inputText class="inputs" value="#{ciclistaBeanDB.nombre}" />
            <h:inputText class="inputs" value="#{ciclistaBeanDB.nacionalidad}" />
            <h:inputText class="inputs" value="#{ciclistaBeanDB.equipo}" />
        </div>
        <h:commandButton class="btn" action="#{ciclistaBeanDB.create()}" value="Create" />
   </h:form>
```

I  get  error:  method not found   because  i don't pass the  `Ciclista c` object  in `crear(//here)`
since   i   don't  have the  object per se,  just  its attributes how do I  proceed ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the `MethodNotFoundException`, because you wrote *crear* instead of *Create*.

But the right way to do it, would be to call a `save()` method without arguments, which is responsible to assemble your object you want to persist.

Since you are already binding your input fields to bean properties, all you would need to do is, use a method like this:

```
public String save(){
   Ciclista c = new Ciclista();
   c.setNombre(this.nombre);
   c.setNacionalidad(this.nacionalidad);
   c.setEquipo(this.equipo);

   create(c);
   return "Administrador?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

your commandbutton now should target the `save()` method of your bean. The input values in the form will be inserted into your baking bean properties and the `save()` method would assemble the instance and finally calls your persist-method.

```
<h:commandButton class="btn" action="#{ciclistaBeanDB.save}" value="Create" />
```

Usually you should not call the `DatabaseBean` directly, but kind of a `Controller` - or how ever one would like to call it. This Bean then should *utilize* your database-service which should only be responsible for CRUD-Functionality.

At least for big applications it would be a mess having the databasemethods and other (view-related) methods mixed in one class.

Comment: hehe   actually  the error was here a  typo error  but  in the actual file  the methods are correct,  but thank you  this solved my  question,  am  I  understand  this  could  be related to  `Dependency Injection`  by any chance do you know a link I  can learn this ?